# Vuejs : v-model with multiple checkbox in v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have some questions about using v-model with "complex" object. Here's my code:

```
<v-list v-for="(facet, facetName) in getFacets" :key="facetName">
 <v-list-tile-content v-for='valueFacet in facet" :key="valueFacet.key">
  <v-checkbox v-model="selectedFacets[facetName]" :value="valueFacet.key"></v-checkbox>
 </v-list-tile-content>
</v-list>
```

And here's my data / init:

```
data() {
 return {
  selectedFacets: {}
 }
},
created: function() {
 // I initialize my object with all my facets here
 config.facets.forEarch(facet => {
  this.selectedFacets[facet] = [];
 });
}
```

Some explanation: each facet has multiple checkbox representing values. We can select multiple values. My object has to be like this :

```
selectedFacets: { facet1 : [value1, value2], facet2: [value12, value 13]
```

With this code, each time I select one value, it will remove the previous one.

I tried to initalize my object in my data like this without using created function:

```
data() {
 return {
  selectedFacets: { "facetName" : [], "facetName2" : []}
 }
}
```

and it works fine. All my values for each facet are added in the right array. But I need to initialize my object and facet names with my conf and if I don't initialize my object in my data, it does not work. I tried with computed / created, by getting my object from my store, but it keeps adding value by removing the previous one.

Any idea about what I do wrong ? Thanks.

Comment: I've asked a similar question some time ago and you might find this useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49582035/vue-multiple-radio-inputs-checked-value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just initialize your object with `Vue.set`:

```
created: function() {
   config.facets.forEach(facet => {
     Vue.set(this.selectedFacets, facet, []);
   });
}
```

When component initializes template it doesn't know about `selectedFacets[facetName]` so to make it reactive and correct working with `v-model` you should use `Vue.set` mutator.

Comment: Thanks ! I use `this.$set` instead of `Vue.set` but otherwise it works fine.